# How to handle large file with low memory usage in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, curl

I would like to know how to handle large file with lower memory usage in PHP 5.6

My PHP5.6 API behavior is firstly receiving a zip file from end user (browser) via POST method.

After receiving POST zip file, I use `file_get_contents()` to transfer POST zip data to String.

Then I use php-curl-class v7.2 + PUT method to send the final String to another server2, like this:

```
$this -> curl -> put($url, file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']));
```

My problem is, when the zip file is larger than 2GB (e.q. 3.2GB), `file_get_contents` will truncate the file to become 2GB only.

And also, in order to handle large zip file, I need to prepare that much physical memory on machine.

How can I handle this situation with large file in PHP 5.6? To lower the memory usage and be able to send large file to another server2?

Thanks.

Comment: i dont understand why you would ever need `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Because I need to pass the file content to curl put method.

Comment: use raw curl, you can stream the file, and not waist the memory.

Comment: How to use raw curl?